# Compile ffmpeg with x265 and fdk-aac on Minibian - dependencies not found

Tags: gcc, ffmpeg, compilation, raspberry-pi, libx265

I am trying to get a live streaming device to work on a raspberry pi. I am running [minibian](https://minibianpi.wordpress.com/). I roughly follow [this guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/RaspberryPi) without the cross compiling.

My problem is probably with the compilation of ffmpeg. I downloaded and compiled both x265 and fdk-aac and compiled them. Next I have to compile ffmpeg, which is in the same folder as the other ones, but the compiler can't find any of the dependencies. x265 also cannot be found using pkg-config, which is the error it produces when I try to run `./configure.`

I directly cloned everything into one folder, so that in a folder called `ffmpeg_files` there are three other folders: `ffmpeg`, `fdk-aac` and `x265`. How do I properly include these dependencies so I can enable them when I compile ffmpeg?

Thank you!

---

Okay, so this is not really an answer to this question.

After a long time of trial and error and a lot of help by the great user [Mulvya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5726027/mulvya) I decided not to use Minibian, but Raspbian Stretch Lite. There, everything worked very smoothly. Just remember to run `sudo ldconfig` after installing the codec libraries like x264/x265 or fdk-aac.

Thanks everybody for your help!

Comment: Check the last few lines of `ffbuild/config.log` and see if ffmpeg can't locate x265 or a compile test fails.

Comment: There are a bunch of `undefined reference to 'pow'` and such, like compile test failures? In the end it says `collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status` and `ERROR: libfdk_aac not found`

Comment: So x265 was found? Share the whole file.

Comment: there you go: https://pastebin.com/jy03t65C

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162105/discussion-between-mulvya-and-mneumann).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was stuck getting the same error, and this solution worked for me:

First check if pkg-config can find x265:

```
$ pkg-config --modversion x265
```

> Package x265 was not found in the pkg-config search path.

Perhaps you should add the directory containing `x265.pc` to the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable:

> No package 'x265' found.

```
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig

$ pkg-config --modversion x265

0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Very much an amateur here, with perhaps even less grasp on the workings of stackoverflow than software compilation, but I hope some positive feedback might help someone else, just as Mulyva has helped me.

After trying and failing to compile ffmpeg on Ubuntu 17.10 (and 16.04 within a virtual machine) with the same error message as the OP and countless others. Compiling x265 rather than using the version in the Ubuntu repos, and using Mulyva's advice in the later chat - "Try with `./configure --enable-static --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-libx265 --extra-libs=-lm --extra-libs=-lstdc++ --enable-libfdk_aac --extra-libs=-lm --extra-libs=-lstdc++`" - has it working for me. Thank you!

Apologies if posting here is embarrasingly out of place...

Comment: Your answer is not out of place at all! I am away from the device, but I will try your solution on Tuesday. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, your suggestion did not work on my system either. It seems to be missing another library. Thank you for your answer!